# Pandas Bar Chart Comparing Days of Two Different Years

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, compare, bar-chart

What I am trying to do is produce a bar chart comparing the sales numbers of Christmas week 2019 vs 2020; the visualization I have in mind is having two bars (two sales numbers) represented as one day. So Monday would have one bar for 2019 and next to it a second bar for Monday 2020 and then it would follow for the rest of the days.

**My dataframe**

```
christmas_week = {'Date':['2019-12-27', '2019-12-25', '2019-12-26', '2019-12-24', '2019-12-23', '2019-12-28', '2019-12-29', '2020-12-26', '2020-12-24', '2020-12-25', '2020-12-22', '2020-12-21', '2020-12-27', '2020-12-23'], 'Sales':['842', '955', '825', '357', '699', '610', '149', '866', '781', '549', '998', '848', '310', '477']}
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame(christmas_week)
```

**Converted Date column to datetime**

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

**Added a column Day of Week and assigned it name of the days**

```
df['Day of Week'] = df['Date'].dt.day_name()
```

**Converted Sales column to numeric**

```
df[['Sales']] = df[['Sales']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

**Rearranged the columns just to look nicer**

```
df = df[["Date","Day of Week","Sales"]]
```

Now I tried many options, on my own and googling around, and the closest that I got to producing a visual I had in my mind was creating a pivot table and then creating a graph from a code I found.

**Created a pivot table**

```
df_pivot = df.pivot(index='Day of Week', columns='Date', values='Sales')
```

**Creating the plot**

```
df_pivot.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(17, 10), rot=0)                                       
plt.title("Christmas Week Comparison", y=1.013, fontsize=22)
plt.xlabel("Date [Month]", labelpad=16)
plt.ylabel("Count [Sales]", labelpad=16);
```

The days are not in order which I am trying to figure out how to solve. Could be that I have to go back to my dataframe and add another column to map the days for them to be in the correct order when the graph is created?

The visual of the graph is also not appealing I know (the colors, the bars and the legend) but that is something I can figure out. I would just like the days to be in the correct order.

[image]

Comment: Import the `calendar` library for an ordered list of days. `df['Day of Week'] = pd.Categorical(df['Day of Week'], categories=list(calendar.day_name), ordered=True)` before you do `df.pivot`. The column needs to be categorically ordered.

Comment: Add up a bit, your table looks a bit ambiguous, as all the dates are individually single data.. Can try `groupby` with aggregation function. Also suggest you check on searborn's `catplot` , it is easier than using `matplotlib`.

Comment: Thank you so much @TrentonMcKinney that worked! The bar chart is now in the correct order

Comment: @CalebChong I will definitely try groupby and you are right, seaborn, which I've just started with, does seem easier than matplot... also visually the graphs look better

Comment: seaborn is just a high-level api for matplotlib